# Создание дочернего объекта из префаба

Tags: c#, unity3d

Из префаба в цикле создаются объекты:

```
    for (int YY = 0; YY < row; YY++)
    {
        for (int XX = 0; XX < col; XX++)
        {
            map[XX, YY] = Instantiate(Box, MyPoze, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        }
    }
```

Нужно каждому объекту создать дочерний объект, тоже из префаба. (первый объект - ячейка, спрайт, второй - 3д текст).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то нужно воспользоваться **[Transform.SetParent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/Transform.SetParent.html)**, с помощью которого можно установить один объект в другой. Выглядит это примерно так:

```
childGO.transform.SetParent(parentGO);
```

Дословно он говорит, что нужно некоему объекту (childGO) сделать родителем другой объект.

Более подробный пример:

```
public GameObject player;

//Invoked when a button is clicked.
public void Example(Transform newParent)
{
    //Sets "newParent" as the new parent of the player GameObject.
    player.transform.SetParent(newParent);

    //Same as above, except this makes the player keep its local orientation rather than its global orientation.
    player.transform.SetParent(newParent, false);
}
```

Здесь мы объект "игрок" встраиваем в Transform объекта `newParent`.

---

Соответственно генерируете один объект и другой. Затем над к одному из них применяете вышеприведенный метод.

Comment: про setparent я знаю, но как это сделать на моем примере, а то у меня ничего не получилось?

Comment: @ВадимМороз на вашем примере я ничего не понял....что это за код с массивом и   причем тут  дочерние объекты......................вы генерируете из префаба некий бокс, затем генерируете из префаба некий текст, затем один сгенерированный объект делаете дочерним по отношению к другому за счет `SetParent`

Answer (score 0):

Для моего случая код будет таким, вдруг кому понадобится

```
public GameObject Box;
public GameObject Txt;
for (int YY = 0; YY < row; YY++)
{
    for (int XX = 0; XX < col; XX++)
    {
        map[XX, YY] = Instantiate(Box, MyPoze, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        GameObject text = Instantiate (Txt) as GameObject;
        text.transform.SetParent(map[XX, YY].transform,false);
    }
}
```